# Multiple conditions in C++ if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am very new to the concept of programming in C++. I am wanting to have a multi condition if statement using the `||` (or) and the `&&` (and) in one statement. When I ask my college professor about it. She told it was possible and then insulted my limited knowledge on the subject. All examples I have access to show a multi && statement and only one showing the `||`. It does not show them being used together. I would like to learn how to get the line working. I will attach the code I have. The problem area is the last bit of coding.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cstring>

using namespace std;

main()
{
    
    const int maximumHours = 774;
    char customerPackage;
    double hoursUsed = 0,
           packageA = 9.95,
           packageB = 14.95,
           packageC = 19.95,
           overPackageA = 2.00,
           overPackageB = 1.00,
           overTime = 0,
           amountDue = 0,
           excessCharged = 0;
    
    cout << "Please enter the customer's package: ";
    cin >> customerPackage;
    
    switch (customerPackage)
    {
        case 'a' :
            cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
                cin >> hoursUsed;
            break;
        
        case 'A' :
            cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
                cin >> hoursUsed;
            break;
        
        case 'b' :
            cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
                cin >> hoursUsed;
            break;
        
        case 'B' :
            cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
                cin >> hoursUsed;
            break;
          
        case 'c' :
            cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
                cin >> hoursUsed;
            break;
        
        case 'C' :
            cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
            cin >> hoursUsed;
            break;        
        default: cout << "Error." 
            << " Please enter the customer's purchased package: ";
        cin >> customerPackage;
    }    
            
    if ( customerPackage ='a' || customerPackage ='A' && hoursUsed >= 10)           
        amountDue = packageA;
        else
            overTime = packageA - hoursUsed;
            excessCharged = overTime * overPackageA;
            amountDue = packageA + excessCharged;
}
```

Comment: Do comparison with `==`, not `=`. And be sure to use `()` to disambiguate your conditions. Otherwise.. what's wrong? Calling your code a "problem area" doesn't give us much to go on in terms of figuring out what you want it to do that it doesn't.

Comment: comparison operator is *==* on c/c++

Comment: Also, do yourself a favor and place parenthesis around each compare, just so that you and everyone else is sure of the order of the && and || above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use 2 or more OR conditions in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8781447/608639)

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is that `&&` has higher precedence than `||` so you need parens. As noted in a comment you also need to use `==` instead of assignment (`=`):

`if ( (customerPackage =='a' || customerPackage =='A') && hoursUsed >= 10)`

Answer (score 7):

Others have already helped you with the problem you've noticed. I'll start with a separate problem you apparently haven't noticed (yet):

```
    else
        overTime = packageA - hoursUsed;
        excessCharged = overTime * overPackageA;
        amountDue = packageA + excessCharged;
```

If you want all three of those statements controlled by the `else`, you need to enclose them in braces to create a compound statement:

```
else {
    overTime = packagA - hoursUsed;
    excessCharged = overTime * overPackageA;
    amountDue = packageA + excessCharged;
}
```

As it stands right now, your code is really:

```
    else
        overTime = packageA - hoursUsed;
    excessCharged = overTime * overPackageA;
    amountDue = packageA + excessCharged;
```

I.e., the computations for `excessCharged` and `amountDue` are carried out *regardless* of whether the condition in the `if` statement was true or false.

I'd also note that your `switch` statement doesn't really accomplish much:

```
switch (customerPackage)
{
    case 'a' :
        cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
            cin >> hoursUsed;
        break;

    case 'A' :
        cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
            cin >> hoursUsed;
        break;

    case 'b' :
        cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
            cin >> hoursUsed;
        break;

    case 'B' :
        cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
            cin >> hoursUsed;
        break;

    case 'c' :
        cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
            cin >> hoursUsed;
        break;

    case 'C' :
        cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
        cin >> hoursUsed;
        break;        
    default: cout << "Error." 
        << " Please enter the customer's purchased package: ";
```

In particular, you take exactly the same action for all the cases (except the default). You can simplify this a bit by using fall-through cases:

```
switch (customerPackage) {
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
    case 'b':
    case 'B':
    case 'c':
    case 'C':
            cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
            cin >> hoursUsed;
            break;
    default:
         cout << "Error " /* ... */;
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider something like:

```
static const char valid[] = "aAbBcC";

if (strchr(valid, userPackage)) {
    cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
    cin >> hoursUsed;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Error: Please enter the customer's purchased package";
    std::cin >> userPackage;
}
```

Personally, however, I'd structure things a bit differently: first get one valid input, then get the next:

```
do { 
    std::cout << "Please enter the customer's purchased package (a, b, or c): ";
    std::cin >> userPackage;
} while (!strchr(valid, userPackage));

std::cout << "Please enter the number of hours used: ";
std::cin >> hoursUsed;

if (tolower(customerPackage == 'a') && hoursUsed >= 10)
// ...
```

Comment: First off thank you to all who are helping me. I have made changes base off the information shared here and give credit where it is due. I am almost done with the program. I am having two issues. one is the problem is going thru all the packages and computing the wrong amounts. I have gone back and made the suggested changes for the issue of not falling out of if statement when needed. I know it is some small step i am missing. Again thanks to all.

Answer (score 5):

```
if ( customerPackage ='a' || customerPackage ='A' && hoursUsed >= 10)
```

You are *so* close to having the right answer. Let me give you two hints:

1. The `=` operator is not the same as the `==` operator. `=` is the assignment operator. It evaluates its right-hand-side and stores the result in the variable named on its left-hand-side. You want `==`, the equality operator. It tests to see if its right-hand side and its left-hand-side are equal.
2. Use parenthesis `( ... )` to enforce your order-of-evaluation intention. You clearly mean to say "If either `customerPackage` is `'a'` or it is `'A'`, and also `hoursUsed` is sufficiently large, then ...".

Try this line:

```
if ( (customerPackage == 'a' || customerPackage == 'A') && hoursUsed >= 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use parentheses to specify the order in which the boolean operators are executed.  You probably want to evaluate the `||` first, so you'd use:

```
if ((customerPackage == 'a' || customerPackage == 'A') && hoursUsed >= 10)
```

The `&&` is normally evaluated first by default, because it has higher precedence, so your code is equivalent to this:

```
if (customerPackage == 'a' || (customerPackage == 'A' && hoursUsed >= 10))
```

Also, as noted in the comments, use `==` for comparison and `=` for assignment.

Comment: thank you. this is very useful information and in the event I will need to call for help again I will stride to be more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

With the new problem you're having (in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216625/mutil-conditional-if-statement-c) you asked), you'll need some restructuring.

```
if ( (customerPackage == 'b' || customerPackage == 'B') && hoursUsed <= 20)

    amountDue = packageB;

    else
    {
        /* calculations */
    }
```

is not correct, that should be

```
if ( customerPackage == 'b' || customerPackage == 'B')
{
   if (hoursUsed <= 20)
   {
      amountDue = packageB;
   }
   else
   {
        /* calculations */
   }
}
```

Otherwise the first statement will only be executed when package=B AND hour=20, otherwise the calculations will be done in all other cases, like when package is A, or C.

Hope this helps!