# IF statement with logical OR

Tags: c++, if-statement, logical-operators

```
if(1 == 2 || 4)
{
cout<<"True";
}
else
{
cout<<"False";
}
```

This is how I read the above. If 1 is equal to 2 or 4, then print true. Otherwise, print false. When this is executed though... true is printed. Obviously I'm misunderstanding something here. 1 is not equal to 2 or 4. Wouldn't that make it false?

Comment: Adding parenthesis to clarify the expression may help you see what is happening: `if ( (1 == 2) || 4)`

Comment: Thank you every one for the comments. I understand now (I think). My confusion comes from a false premise, I believe. In logic, there are logical disjunctions the statement "A or B" is true if A is true. The statement "A or B" is true if B is true. The statement "A or B" is false when neither A or B is true. I looked at (if(1 == 2 || 4) as initially neither true or false but becomes false once it is evaluated, since 1 is not equal to 2 or 4. I guess I've just been looking at it in the wrong way. Thanks again, every one.

Comment: I'm a beginner to C++ (and programming in general) and I've just begun reading programming: principles and practice using C++ by bjarne stroustrup. I had to write an if statement using a logical or operator but something wasn't coming up right. Now I understand that I was looking at it in the wrong way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you use 2 or more OR conditions in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8781447/608639)

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, I've made the same mistake.

Read the sentence again:

> If 1 is equal to 2 or 4, then print true.

The "2" and "4" both refer to the "If 1 is equal to [...]." That means, the sentence is just an abbreviation of

> If 1 is equal to 2 or *1 is equal to* 4, then print true.

This leads us to the `if`-clause

```
if (1 == 2 || 1 == 4)
```

instead.

---

`1 == 2 || 4` is true because `(1 == 2) == false` ORed with `4 == true`, yields true (false OR true = true).

Answer (score 2):

> This is how I read the above. If 1 is equal to 2 or 4, then print true. Otherwise, print false. When this is executed though... true is printed. Obviously I'm misunderstanding something here. 1 is not equal to 2 or 4. Wouldn't that make it false?

No, 1 is equal to 2 or 4. `4` is true (because it's not zero). So anything "or 4" is also true. Therefore "1 is equal to 2 **or 4**" is true.

Comment: Does that mean the following would print true?
    {
    if(1 == 2 || 0)
    {
    cout<<"True";
    }
    else
    {
    cout<<"False";
    }
    }

Comment: @MikeYork No. Because neither side of the or is true. 1 is not equal to 2. 0 is false.

Answer (score 1):

In this your phrase

> If 1 is equal to 2 or 4, then print true

you need to add a pair of words that to get a correct equivalent C++ phrase

> If 1 is equal to 2 or **is equal to** 4, then print true

Thus it will look the following way

```
if ( 1 == 2 or 1 == 4 )
{
    cout << "True";
}
else
{
    cout<<"False";
}
```

As for the original condition

```
1 == 2 || 4
```

then the compiler consideres it the following way (due to the priorities of the operators):

```
( 1 == 2 ) || 4
```

According to the C++ Stanbdard

> The operators == and != both yield true or false, i.e., a result of
>   type bool.

So as 1 == 2 is equal to `false` then you get

```
false || 4
```

where 4 as it is not equal to 0 is converted to boolean `true` and as result the entire condition evaluates to `true`

Answer (score 0):

This not how if statements work in C++.  If you want to know if something is equal to one thing or another thing then it is

```
if (this == this_thing || this == another_thing)
```

What you have

```
if(1 == 2 || 4)
```

Gets evaluated to

```
if ((1 == 2) || 4)
if (false || true)
if (true)
```

So the if statement will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

It's evaluating to true because if you check for the boolean value of just an integer (like you're doing with the number 4), it will evaluate to true. Like the people said above, you have to split it up.