# Why comparing three variables together with == evaluates to false?

Tags: c++

The output of the following program is "they are not equal", but I'd expect "they are equal" as the three compared variables (`x`,`y`, and `z`) are equal. Why?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int y, x, z;
    y = 3;
    x = 3;
    z = 3;

    if (x == y == z)
    {
        std::cout << "they are equal\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "they are not equal\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781447/can-you-use-2-or-more-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement

Comment: `if (x == y == z)` does not do what you think

Comment: so i can't equivalent 3 numbers in one line without equivalent each 2 numbers separately?

Comment: ***so i can't equivalent 3 numbers in one line without equivalent each 2 numbers separately?*** You are correct you can't do that in a single expression

Comment: correct. because a comparison evaluates to a boolean value, and then you're comparing that to a number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because of the way expression and types are evaluated.

Let's evaluate the leftmost `==`

```
x == y ...
```

This evaluates to true. Let's rewrite the expression:

```
//  x == y
if (true   == z) {
    // ...
}
```

The `true` is a boolean value. A boolean value cannot be directly compared to an `int`. A conversion from the boolean to an integer must occur, and the result is `1` (yes, `true` == `1`). Let's rewrite the expression to its equivalent value:

```
//  true
if (1    == z) {
    //    ^--- that's false
}
```

But `z` isn't equal to `1`. That expression is false!

Instead, you should separate both boolean expressions:

```
if (x == y && y == z) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And now some practical C++17 applications. No SFINAE necessary.

```cpp
//----------------------------------
// constexpr lambda requires C++17
auto eq3 = [] (auto v1, auto v2, auto v3) constexpr -> bool
{
    return ( v1 == v2 ) && ( v2 == v3 );
};
```

Usage is simple but fully compile time

```cpp
constexpr auto same_ = eq3(42,42,42);
std::bool_constant< eq3(42,42,42) > twins_ ;
```

For comparing a whole sequences of values, concept is the same, impementation is a little bit more involved.

```cpp
template<typename ... T>
constexpr bool all_equal ( const T & ... args_ )  
{
    if ((sizeof...( args_) ) < 2) return true;
    // for non recursive version
    const auto il_ = { args_ ... };
    // compare them all to the first
    auto first_ = *(il_.begin()) ;
    // assumption
    bool rezult_{ true }; 
    for ( auto && elem_ : il_) {
        // yes I know, first cycle compares first_ to itself ...
        rezult_ = rezult_ && ( first_ == elem_ );
        // short circuit-ing
        if (!rezult_) break;
    }
    return rezult_; 
};
```

"just" a function, compile time, again no variadic template trickery.

```cpp
    bool_constant< all_equal(42,42,42,42,42,42,42) > same_ ;
    cout << endl << boolalpha <<  same_() ;

    bool_constant< all_equal(42,43,44,45,46,47) > not_same_ ;
    cout << endl << boolalpha <<  not_same_() ;
```

Mandatory [Wandbox is here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/syGgnzOlWjOXaCc6).

ps: somewhat predictable `all_equal` does not compile using the very latest CL also known as MSVC or Visual Studio.