# How to compare 2D array 3 char elements in if statement?

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, compare

In line no 20,27,32,36 even though the value is true the count value is not increasing at the end it is showing 0 count value. i think i have made an mistake while comparing array. i dont know how to compare an char element 2d array
the input is
1
xxx
ooo

---

the answer must be 3
the code is as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; n++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            char t[2][2];
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                scanf("%c %c %c", &t[i][0], &t[i][1], &t[i][2]);
            }
            if (t[0][0] == '_' || t[0][1] == '_' || t[0][2] == '_' || t[1][0] == '_' || t[1][1] == '_' || t[1][2] == '_' || t[2][0] == '_' || t[2][1] == '_' || t[2][2] == '_')
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    if (t[j][0] == t[j][1] == t[j][2])
                    {
20)                        count++;
                    }
                }
                for (int q = 0; q < 3; q++)
                {
                    if (t[0][q] == t[1][q] == t[2][q])
                    {
27)                        count++;
                    }
                }
                if (t[0][0] == t[1][1] == t[2][2])
                {
32)                    count++;
                }
                else if (t[0][2] == t[1][1] == t[2][0])
                {
36)                    count++;
                }
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    printf("%d", 2);
                }
                else if (count == 1)
                {
                    printf("%d", 1);
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    printf("%d", 3);
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if (x == y == z)` should be `if (x == y && y == z)`. The former checks whether `x` is equal to `y`, and then compares `z` with either 0 or 1. The latter verifies that `x`, `y` and `z` all have the same value.

Comment: Can you simplify your code to eliminate distractions? For example, initialize `int n = 1;` instead of reading the value from the input. At which point, your outer `for` loop has only one iteration, so you could keep the loop body but drop the `for` line. Focus on the troublesome comparison. See [mre].

Comment: `char t[2][2];` can accomodate 4 elements and this `for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)` loop will execute 3 times and `scanf("%c %c %c", &t[i][0], &t[i][1], &t[i][2]);` is scaning for 3 elements in each iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271178/why-comparing-three-variables-together-with-evaluates-to-false

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Code below is probably what you're looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, count=0; char s[20];
    printf("Enter total number of iterations (n): ");
    scanf("%s", s);    // Don't use %d. If you use %d and input a character, \
                          buffer issues arise.
    printf("\n");
    n = atoi(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;
        char t[3][3];
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            printf("Enter 3 chars with spaces between them: ");
            scanf(" %c %c %c", &t[x][0], &t[x][1], &t[x][2]);  // Space before\
                                                     the first %c makes scanf \
                                                     skip leading whitespace.
            printf("\n");
        }
    
        printf("n is %d\n\
t[0][0] = %c, t[0][1] = %c, t[0][2] = %c\n\
t[1][0] = %c, t[1][1] = %c, t[1][2] = %c\n\
t[2][0] = %c, t[2][1] = %c, t[2][2] = %c\n", n, \
\
t[0][0],      t[0][1],      t[0][2], \
t[1][0],      t[1][1],      t[1][2], \
t[2][0],      t[2][1],      t[2][2]);
        
        if (t[0][0] == '_' || t[0][1] == '_' || t[0][2] == '_' || \
            t[1][0] == '_' || t[1][1] == '_' || t[1][2] == '_' || \
            t[2][0] == '_' || t[2][1] == '_' || t[2][2] == '_')
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if ((t[j][0] == t[j][1]) && (t[j][1] == t[j][2]))
                {
                       count++;
                }
            }
            for (int q = 0; q < 3; q++)
            {
                if ((t[0][q] == t[1][q]) && (t[1][q] == t[2][q]))
                {
                       count++;
                }
            }
            if ((t[0][0] == t[1][1]) && (t[1][1] == t[2][2]))
            {
                   count++;
            }
            else if ((t[0][2] == t[1][1]) && (t[1][1] == t[2][0]))
            {
                   count++;
            }
            if (count == 0)
            {
                printf("%d", 2);
            }
            else if (count == 1)
            {
                printf("%d", 1);
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                printf("%d", 3);
            }
        }
        
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Output is as follows (`count` seems to be `> 1`, so `3` is printed):

```
Enter total number of iterations (n): 1

Enter 3 chars with spaces between them: x x x

Enter 3 chars with spaces between them: o o o

Enter 3 chars with spaces between them: _ _ _

n is 1
t[0][0] = x, t[0][1] = x, t[0][2] = x
t[1][0] = o, t[1][1] = o, t[1][2] = o
t[2][0] = _, t[2][1] = _, t[2][2] = _
3
```

Comment: Code-only answers are rarely useful to future visitors with the same question. Better would be to explain the changes in words, relegating the code to an illustration of the explanation.

Comment: @JaMiT. Variety of reasons why I chose to answer as I did: 1. I didn't want to make my answer too long. 2. I didn't want to harp on the mistakes of the person who posted the question. 3. By showing actual execution I felt that: a. I could connect better with the questions asked. b. events were made plain & more explanation was unnecessary. 4. I have other things to do & I cannot spend more time. Good luck !