# Is it valid to use 2 string or char options in a while statement?

Tags: c++

Is it okay to use this `string answer = "A || B";`? than using this `if (answer == A || answer == B)?`.

I want to put two condition in the `while statement` in the program but I'm having a hard time solving it since it get's an error.

```cpp
    // variables
    string answerA = "Coin";
    string guess;
    int guessCount = 0;
    int guessLimit = 3; 
    bool outOfGuesses = false;

    cout << "Question A!\n" << endl;
    cout << "A. What has a head and a tail, but no body?\n";

        // if the answer is not correct, ask again only 3 times
    while (answerA != guess && !outOfGuesses) {
        if (guessCount < guessLimit) {
            cout << "Answer: ";
            cin >> guess;
            guessCount++;
        } else {
            outOfGuesses = true;
        }
    }

    if (outOfGuesses)
    {
        cout << "Your answers are all wrong! Better luck next time :)";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Your answer is Correct! ";
    }
```

Comment: Using `string answer = "A || B";` is valid, but it doesn't mean to have 2 options unless you parse the string later to extract the 2 options.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781447/can-you-use-2-or-more-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement

Comment: @MikeCAT how to parse and extract, sir?

Comment: @NathanOliver Is it possible to put it in a while if statement?

Comment: Did you read the link?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, Sir. but my problem is I want to put it in my While if statements. I tried it several times but it only causes error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use 2 or more OR conditions in an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781447/can-you-use-2-or-more-or-conditions-in-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 1):

One `std::string` can hold only one string. You can use [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) to hold a set of multiple strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

int main(void) {
    std::unordered_set<std::string> accept_list = {"A", "B"};
    std::string answer = "A";

    if (accept_list.find(answer) != accept_list.end()) {
        std::cout << "accept\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "reject\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(`std::unordered_set` is available since C++11. If your compiler doesn't support that, try [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead. Also initializer lists like `accept_list = {"A", "B"}` is since C++11, you may have to add each candidates separately in that case)